# How to dowload and install Visual Studio 15.8 Preview

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-provisioning

I'm trying to deploy my Visual Studio Xamarin app to my iPad Pro 12.9 but automatic provisioning is not working.

How can I get VS 15.8 Preview (4) to download and install, so I can use its Automatic Provisioning?

Comment: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Comment: Do I understand correctly that currently you're using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 15.7 and have macOS connected? Do you have an Apple developer account (paid, not free)?